# How to add dark mode for anonymous users

Tags: django, darkmode

I am using Django, I added dark mode to my website. But only for logged in users, is there a way to add it for anonymous users?

Code:

```
class Mood(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeginKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name=dark)
```

And I check if it exists in template views function:

```
dark = Mood.object.filter(user=request.user)

Context={'dark':dark}
```

Then I check for it in the template

```
 {% if dark %}
add css file for dark mood
{%else%}
Css light mood file
{%endif%}
```

Now the only way to add dark mode is for logged in users, is there another way to do it for anonymous ones?

Answer (score 3):

You can store the mode a user prefers in a [session [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/) variable. Suppose there is a view that toggles the mode a user wants to use:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def toggle_css_mode(request):
    css_mode = request.session.get('css_mode', 'light')
    request.session['css_mode'] = 'dark' if css_mode == 'light' else 'light'
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')) # redirect to last page or index / home page if none
```

You would have some anchor tag that links to this view to toggle the css mode.

Now in your templates you can render the relevant css by:

```
{% if request.session.css_mode == "dark" %}
    css file for dark mode
{% else %}
    css file for light mode
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Context={'dark':dark}
Then I check for it in the template

{% if dark %}
add css file for dark mood
{%else%}
Css light mood file
{%endif%}